# Problem installing software

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, software-sources

I'm completely new to the Ubuntu world (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04). I encountered a very annoying problem when trying to install software. When I run

```
sudo apt-get application_name
```

nothing happens(installation freezes at 10% or whatever
[whatch here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24924076/)
  I'm just a beginner so i don't know how to fix it.
In usc all the apps have disappeared(except the apps already installed).
Just a suggestion:it might be a problem with my sources?
Please help me to find and fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the full output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: please post the output of these commands: `sudo dpkg --configure -a ` , `sudo apt-get install -f` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: You can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for the output of `apt-get update` etc. to not trigger the spam filter for too many URLs.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the current packaging problem remove the `oracle-java9-installer` package:

```
sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX dpkg -r oracle-java9-installer && sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-get install -f
```

This should enable you to install packages again.

If you need help installing Oracle Java 9 please open a new question about it specifically.

Comment: I tried to remove oracle java 9 installer but i receive this:E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @fernandinho: Please try the commands in my updated answer. If there's still an error message please edit your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of the command that resulted in an error. Thanks.

Comment: @fernandinho: Could you please edit your question, when you want to add information like I requested? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: after removing java9 -set-default and java9 instaler:florindobre@florindobre-MS-7387:~$ sudo apt-get install banshee
[sudo] password for florindobre: 
Citire liste de pachete... Terminat
Se construiește arborele de dependență       
Se citesc informațiile de stare... Terminat
Pachetul banshee nu este disponibil, dar este menționat de către alt pachet.
Aceasta ar putea însemna că pachetul lipsește, s-a învechit, sau
este disponibil numai din altă sursă

E: Package 'banshee' has no installation candidate